# Dynamically add element to layout

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic

I am quite new to developing apps. Still I would have thought that this is a basic action, so if there is already a solved thread I would be OK with the link. But since I am searching for over 2 hours for this I am asking anyway:

I want to dynamically add an element to my layout every time the user clicks a button.

By now I have this:

XML (R.layout.game.xml)

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/submit_choice" 
        android:onClick="submitChoice"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Java

```
  public void submitChoice(View view)
    {
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText("text");

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);

        ll.addView(View.inflate(ll.getContext(), R.layout.game, null));
        ll.addView(textView);
        setContentView(ll);
    }
```

Since the XML file does not change, it only works once.

So how can I add a second text when the user clicks the button a second time (without changing the XML file)? Examples are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from this line, that recreate the whole layout every time:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
```

You should define it and `setContentView(ll)` outside the `submitChoice` function. Then on click only create and add the `textView` , then call `ll.invalidate();` to see the changes.

Something like:

```
LinearLayout ll;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.game);
            ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_game);    
        }

// More code...

public void submitChoice(View view) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setTextSize(40);
            textView.setText("text");

            ll.addView(textView);
            ll.invalidate();
        }
```

where `ll_game` is the id you have to set in xml for your `LinearLayout`.